# How to write an argument for an existing command

Tags: bash

What I want to do is write an argument for tr that reverses the text for rot13 codes.

I want to make this

```
tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'
```

Just this

```
tr -r
```

And have the -r argument do what the first command does

Comment: You can use alias, instead of difficult work with arguments. In your `.bashrc` append one line: `alias trr="tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'"` and use `trr` alias.

Answer (score 3):

Use a shell function that wraps the `tr` command:

```
tr () {
  if [[ $1 == "-r" ]]; then
    shift
    set -- '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]' "$@"
  fi
  command tr "$@"
}
```

Check that "regular" tr works:

```
$ echo "Hello World!" | tr 'aeiou' 'AEIOU' 
HEllO WOrld!
```

And now, use the rot13 option

```
$ echo "Hello World!" | tr 'aeiou' 'AEIOU' | tr -r
URyyB JBeyq!
$ echo "Hello World!" | tr 'aeiou' 'AEIOU' | tr -r | tr -r
HEllO WOrld!
```